# Print categories and most viewed articles

Tags: categories, sidebar

I need to show all the categories (not child) in a sidebar and the 4 articles with the large number of views. The page is not a default wp blog page but it's custom.

```
<div class="container no-padding blog">

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 card">

    <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>            
            <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="post clearfix">

                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">

                            <div class="blog-top">

                                <p><?php the_date('d M Y', '<span>', '</span>'); ?></p>

                                    <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>

                            </div></a>

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <div class="evidenza cover" style="background-image:url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>)"></div></a>

                        <div class="blog-excerpt">

                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                        </div>

                    </div>

            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    </div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 sidebar">

    <div class="sidebar-widget">

        // here I need to print categories and 4 articles

    </div>

</div>
```

I hope someone help, I'm approaching now with PHP!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [wp_list_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) and [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). Regarding, _"with the large number of views"_ you'll need an internal method of measuring views that also allows to query internally by. WP by default doesn't count or query views.

Comment: Thank you for the response! So I need to find a plugin that fits my needs! I'm going to set up the list categories for now! Best regards